# Disable kubernetes enableServiceLinks globally?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Is there a way to disable service links globally. There's a field in `podSpec`:

```
enableServiceLinks: false
```

but it's `true` by default. I couldn't find anything in kubelet to kill it. Or is there some cool admission webhook toolchain I could use

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Kubernetes-native policy engine called [Kyverno](https://kyverno.io/). Kyverno policies can validate, **mutate** (see: [Mutate Resources](https://kyverno.io/docs/writing-policies/mutate/)), and generate Kubernetes resources.

A Kyverno policy is a collection of rules that can be applied to the entire cluster (`ClusterPolicy`) or to the specific namespace (`Policy`).

---

I will create an example to illustrate how it may work.

First we need to install Kyverno, you have the option of installing Kyverno directly from the latest release manifest, or using Helm (see: [Quick Start guide](https://kyverno.io/docs/introduction/#quick-start)):

```
$ kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kyverno/kyverno/main/definitions/release/install.yaml
```

After successful installation, we can create a simple `ClusterPolicy`:

```
$ cat strategic-merge-patch.yaml
apiVersion: kyverno.io/v1
kind: ClusterPolicy
metadata:
  name: strategic-merge-patch
spec:
  rules:
  - name: enableServiceLinks_false_globally
    match:
      resources:
        kinds:
        - Pod
    mutate:
      patchStrategicMerge:
        spec:
          enableServiceLinks: false

$ kubectl apply -f strategic-merge-patch.yaml
clusterpolicy.kyverno.io/strategic-merge-patch created

$ kubectl get clusterpolicy
NAME                    BACKGROUND   ACTION   READY
strategic-merge-patch   true         audit    true
```

This policy adds `enableServiceLinks: false` to the newly created Pod.

Let's create a Pod and check if it works as expected:

```
$ kubectl run app-1 --image=nginx
pod/app-1 created

$ kubectl get pod app-1 -oyaml | grep "enableServiceLinks:"
  enableServiceLinks: false
```

It also works with `Deployments`, `StatefulSets`, `DaemonSets` etc.:

```
$ kubectl create deployment deploy-1 --image=nginx
deployment.apps/deploy-1 created

$ kubectl get pod deploy-1-7cfc5d6879-kfdlh -oyaml | grep "enableServiceLinks:"
  enableServiceLinks: false
```

More examples with detailed explanations can be found in the [Kyverno Writing Policies documentation](https://kyverno.io/docs/writing-policies/).